# how to use multiple checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, crud, checkboxlist

I am creating a angular reactive form, in that form I am using multiple textboxes. for new add() fun it worked proper. But when I am trying to update User value from table It is not working properly.

1. table data: [db data fetched into table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31yyC.png)
2. patching value to form after edit button clicked : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCr6f.png)
3. Updated with one checkbox : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgdZ7.png)
4. not worked as you can see: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Zjo.png)

````
project.ts file
onChecked(e: any) {
    console.log("checkbox ", e.target.value, e.target.checked);
    const checkedValue = e.target.value
    const checked = e.target.checked
    const checkedArray = this.prodform.get('checkBoxes') as FormArray
    if (checked) {
      // console.log(new FormControl(checkedValue)+" : new FormControl(checkedValue)");
      checkedArray.push(new FormControl(checkedValue))
    }
    else {

      let i = 0
      checkedArray.controls.forEach((item) => {
        // console.log(item.value+"item.value");
        console.log("else");

        console.log(item.value + "item");
        console.log(checkedValue + "checkedValue");
        if (item.value == checkedValue) {
          console.log("else-if");
          checkedArray.removeAt(i)
          console.log(item.value + "item");
          console.log(checkedValue + "checkedValue");

        }
        i++;
      })
    }
    console.log(checkedArray.value + " : checkedArray");
  }
``` and template code is
````

{{check}} 
        
        
          
            
          
          
            
          
```

For patching db values to form

```
editProduct(id: any) {
    this.formhide = true
    this.displayflag = false
    this.isUpdate = true
    this.currentID = id
    this.prodservice.getproductById(id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        // console.log("info allproduct() : " + data);
        this.dbproducts = data
        console.log(this.dbproducts, "dbproducts");

        this.prodform.get('productname')?.patchValue(this.dbproducts.productname)
        this.prodform.get('brandname')?.patchValue(this.dbproducts.brandname)
        this.prodform.get('category')?.patchValue(this.dbproducts.category)
        this.prodform.get('date')?.patchValue(this.dbproducts.date)


      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert("there is no data found for given input")
      }
    )
    console.log(this.dbproducts, "edited values");


  }
```

For update button

```
  update(formvalues: any) {

    
    this.prodservice.editproduct(this.currentID, this.prodform.value).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("formvalues : ", formvalues);
      console.log(data);
    })

    // this.messageService.add({
    //   severity: 'success',
    //   summary: 'Service Message', detail: 'Changes done'
    // });

    // this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    //   // let user_id = params.get('category')
    //   // console.log("Current Id : ",user_id);
    //   console.log("params : ", params['id']);

    // })
    this.allProducts()
    this.displayflag = true
    this.formhide = false
    
  }
```

Comment: you can host your code snippet in online compiler like https://stackblitz.com/ so that more people can engage in your question easily.

Comment: Syed Mohammad Fahim Abrar
Ok, thanks.